# Scripting.FileSystemObject vs Server.Execute

Tags: performance, asp-classic, filesystemobject

which one is faster?
(for static html page include)

Comment: I suspect that use of `Server.Execute` will make use of the web server's cache better that FSO.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest solution for static html page include would be **Server Side Includes**:

**foo.asp**

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT"%>
<% Option Explicit %>
<!-- #include file="baz.htm" -->
```

**baz.htm**

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```